# how do you validate a json object in codeigniter?

Tags: json, codeigniter

```
 var trans = { 
     amount: $('#container input:first-child').val(),
     note: $('#container input:last-child').val()
    };  // javascript

 trans =  {
     "amount":"",
     "note":"",
 }  // json 

$trans = $this->input->post('trans');
$t = json_decode($trans);

$amount = $t->amount;
$note = $t->note;

$this->form_validation->set_rules('amount', 'Amount', 'required');
```

the error is

```
  Call to a member function set_rules() on a non-object in......
```

How do you validate a json object?

Comment: what are you trying to do? what is the process of validating you are following?

Answer (score 0):

try to load `form_validation` library in your constructor

```
function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
}
```